# Troubleshooting Hardware with limited resources

Tags: hardware-failure, computer-building, post

I have a newly built computer which won't post, output video, or even beep despite the installed speaker.  The case fans and CPU / GPU fans start up and continue, and the hard drive seems to soon up. Yet, I can get absolutely no response from it.

It has an Asus M5A97 le r2.0 running an fx-8350, with a Thermaltake smart 650W psu.  Even when its 2x4gb ram is removed, the internal speaker does not produce missing memory beeps, leading me to believe one of these three components is failing me - but with no spare hardware or testing rig, I don't know how to determine which.

How should I proceed?

Answer (score 2):

If you take all the RAM out and it doesn't beep to tell you there's no RAM, and assuming the CPU is properly installed and compatible with the motherboard, then the motherboard is busted (most likely).

One thing to check related to compatibility is your installed BIOS version.

According to [Asus' support page](http://www.asus.com/ca-en/Motherboards/M5A97_LE_R20/HelpDesk_CPU/), for that CPU to work, that motherboard requires BIOS version 1006 or higher.

If the board came with a lower BIOS version than that, then you will need a CPU that works with your existing BIOS version so that you can boot the board long enough to update the BIOS to a compatible version.

Welcome to building/repairing computer hardware - you need spare parts... ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try reseating the CPU.

The ability to beep on many motherboards is dependant on being able to communicate with the CPU. Most everything else can be screwed up and the beep codes still be produced, but if not even the CPU is working, the motherboard can't execute any instructions to make the speaker beep.

Answer (score 0):

Since we don't know what the problem is and we don't have many clues, I'm just going to suggest a bunch of ideas that come to mind. You can try them all and use process of elimination to hopefully stumble across a solution.

- Unplug your hard drive, CD drive, and any other non-essential parts since you do not need them to POST.
- Try taking out one of your sticks of RAM in case a stick of RAM is bad.
- Try moving your stick of RAM from slot 1 to slot 3 in case one of your RAM slots is bad.
- Try changing your graphics card to a different PCI Express slot in case your PCI Express slot is bad.
- Try swapping in spare parts, in particular for the RAM. I built a computer one time and that particular RAM did not work with my motherboard for some reason, even though it was the correct type and speed.
- Make sure you installed your CPU correctly. If you have a bent pin, if you didn't depress the arm all the way, etc. that could be causing problems.
- Make sure your heatsink is installed correctly. If your CPU is instantly overheating that can cause shutdowns.
- Make sure you plugged in your 8-pin CPU power cord and your 6 or 8-pin GPU power cord.

If making any of these changes fixes the problem, then you know that was the problem part.

If none of these ideas work, then your next step is to swap out parts one by one until you find the problem part. Process of elimination says that it has to be one of the following: CPU, motherboard, PSU, RAM, or graphics card.